# php mysql slight restructure... or large change?

Tags: php, mysql

I hope you all had a wonderful weekend!

I *had* a piece of code that went like this - quite successfully:

```
if($privs == "100") {

    // Lets set up our page display based on each 100 level users $id.
    $v = $_GET['v']; if ($_GET['v'] == "") $v = $id;
?>
  <table style="width: 100%; height: auto; margin: 0; border: 0;" cellspacing="0">
   <tbody><tr>
<?php
    // Get our list of all the active 100 level team members
    $team100 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM staff_100 WHERE privs='100' AND active='yes'");
    $i = 0;
    while ($row100 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($team100)) {
        $i++;
        if ($i == $v) {
            $bg = $colour1;
            $bc = $colour1;
            $lnkc = " color: #ffffff;";
        } else {
            $bg = "transparent";
            $bc = "#c0c0c0";
            $lnkc = "";
        }
        echo "    <td style=\"background: " . $bg . "; border: 2px solid " . $bc . "; border-top-left-radius: 5px; border-top-right-radius: 5px; border-bottom: 0; text-align: center; padding: 2px 20px;\"><a href=\"./ops.php?v=" . $row100['id'] . "\" style=\"text-decoration: none;" . $lnkc . " display: block;\"><strong>" . $row100['forename'] . " " . $row100['surname'] . "</strong></a></td>\n";
    }
?>
   </tr></tbody>
  </table>

  <table style="width: 100%; height: auto; margin: 0; border: 2px solid <?=$colour1?>; border-top: 0; border-bottom-left-radius: 5px; border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;" cellspacing="0">
   <tbody><tr style="background: <?=$colour1?>;">
    <td class="center" style="width: 10%;"><strong>Claim ID</strong></td>
    <td class="center" style="width: 20%;"><strong>Date received</strong></td>
    <td style="width: 40%;"><strong>Registrar name</strong></td>
    <td class="center" style="width: 13%;"><strong>Claim total</strong></td>
    <td class="center" style="width: 12%;"></td>
   </tr><?php
    // Get the regions and the ready_to_process claims in one db call.
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM registrar_claims WHERE reg_region IN (SELECT region FROM regions WHERE staff_100_id='$v') AND ready_to_process='yes' ORDER BY claim_id ASC");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "\n   <tr style=\"background: " . cycleColours() . ";\">\n";
        echo "    <td class=\"center\">" . $row['claim_id'] . "</td>\n";
        echo "    <td class=\"center\">" . $row['timestamp_3'] . "</td>\n";
        echo "    <td>" . $row['reg_1st_name'] . " " . $row['reg_2nd_name'] . "</td>\n";
        echo "    <td class=\"center\">" . $row['exp_total'] . "</td>\n";
        echo "    <td class=\"center\"><a href=\"./ops.php?c=claimdisplay&amp;id=" . $row['reg_uri'] . "&amp;v=" . $_GET['v'] . "\">View</a></td>\n   </tr>";
    }
?>
</tbody>
  </table>
<?php
}
?>
```

This worked really well as long as I could have the assurance that only staff users with privs level 100 were going to be within the 'staff' table. I no longer have this assurance - all users of all levels are now held in one common staff table so a users 'privs' could be 100, 200, 300 or 400.

I'm a little lost on how to alter my code to make the first table display with only the 100 level staff, and function exactly how it used to when it had table exclusivity. Do I need to totally restructure my code now or am I missing something simple and easy to alter?

Thank you! Comments are always read and appreciated.

Comment: Your SQL is already only getting the rows with the level of 100, from what you've posted here.

Comment: Hi Andrew, yes it is, however the resulting display handled by the php is no longer working. That is where I need the help!

Comment: What do you mean by not working? You should include some details about that in the question.

Comment: The html output generated by the php no longer produces the result it used to do since now all staff are in one table with different 'privs' levels. The staff user 'id' is no longer necessarily sequential or even begins at 1. The first 100 privs level user may be id number 6, for example. So the php/html fails as $i is set to 0 and does not know how to compensate for the irregular results the sql query may return.